# Register a specific movement pattern for an accelorometer (X, Y and Z) readings

Tags: python, azure, analysis, supervised-learning

I have attached an accelerometer on a box, which transmits the accelerometer data to a Raspberry Pi connected to Microsoft Azure IoT central. I am able to send the raw data to the cloud. But I wish to be able to identify certain movement patterns (see image) and whenever a pattern is recognized - it should be able to label it, and translate it to a numeric value of 1.

I imagine supervised ML, where I (somehow) marks the start and the end of a movement, will be the approach to create this algorithm?
But to be honest I don't know how to approach this. Any help or advice will be much appreciated :)

[image: Raw data]

I have a pasted a snippet of the raw accelerometer read outs

[image: output]